# Combining Countif Function With

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using Spreadsheet 2 to count the number of times "I" shows up in the `W column` on Spreadsheet 1, but I only want this counted if value "Yes" is present in the `L column` of spreadsheet 1.

I'm thinking something along the lines of...

```
=countif(spreadsheet1!W2:W9000,"I"IF(spreadsheet1L2:L9000,"Yes"))
```

This has not worked, but may provide a more clear example of what I'm trying to do.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?  If you're using 2007 or greater, try the  countifs formula and post back if that doesn't work.

Comment: try `=countifs(spreadsheet1!W2:W9000,"I",spreadsheet1L2:L9000,"Yes")`

Answer (score 0):

Using countifs as suggested by @sous2817 would work. Sumporduct should also work:

```
=Sumproduct(--(Spredsheet2!W:W="I"),--(Spreadsheet1!L:L="Yes"))
```